# How select class , div , tag in splinter?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am trying to understand splinter functionalities, i tried to find on web but i couldn't found good documentation with pratical examples on splinter so i asked few questions here so that it will help beginner who are trying to learn splinter :

First i am confuse what is actual css selector in splinter , there are two method i see everywhere :

```
browser.find_by_css()
```

or

```
browser.find_by_css_selector()
```

What is the difference between them and why the second one is not working in current splinter ?

Now My original question is how to select any tag which is under any class , how to select any tag which is under any id ?

I tried to find but i found most of stackoverflow questions on a splinter on "how to select option values in dropdown" , And splinter documentation is very good but the problem is they don't have practical sufficient examples for their methods.

So if i have this html code :

```
<div class="medium-widget success-story-category">
                        <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-get-started"></span>Getting Started</h2>
<p>Python can be easy to pick up whether you're a first time programmer or you're experienced with other languages. The following pages are a useful first step to get on your way writing programs with Python!</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers">Beginner's Guide, Programmers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers">Beginner's Guide, Non-Programmers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download">Beginner's Guide, Download &amp; Installation</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Examples">Code sample and snippets for Beginners</a></li>
</ul>

                    </div>
```

Then :

- How to select `<p>` tag data by selecting `class="medium-widget
  success-story-category"`
- second : How select "href" of first `<li>` tag
- third : How get text between first `<li></li>`

Now if there is `<class_name id="something">` like :

```
<nav id="mainnav" class="python-navigation main-navigation do-not-print" role="navigation">


<ul class="navigation menu" role="menubar" aria-label="Main Navigation">



    <li id="about" class="tier-1 element-1   with-supernav" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="/about/" title="" class=" current_item selected selected">About</a>
```

- Now how to select : `<nav id="mainnav" class="python-navigation    main-navigation do-not-print" role="navigation">` with id using find_by_css method (not using find_by_id)
- How get `<a>` link using find_by_css

Comment: Its better that you can ask one question one at  time

Comment: @iamsankalp89 yes i thought about this but if i ask a question for per my little doubt it is not good i think because all are related from same thing and same module so i asked together.

Comment: Its ok, its quite difficult to answer all at once

Comment: @iamsankalp89 should i ask them one by one separately, bro ? There will be many questions  :/

Comment: YES You can ask 2-3 issue in one question, so other can provide solution easily

Comment: Now i asked last big issue in different question after you suggested , here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468644/can-we-change-the-css-html-values-using-splinter-beautiful-soup-or-selenium

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found my answer here i am going to explain so that it will help to other programmers :

First thing `browser.find_by_css_selector()` is not working and i used find_by_css method which worked perfectly so i prefer `find_by_css` method.

How to select `<p>` tag data by selecting `class="medium-widget
success-story-category"`

We can select any class the format is :

`div[class="class_name"]` or `div[any_style_element="value"]`

we can select class 
`class="medium-widget
success-story-category"` 
by 
`div[class="medium-widget
success-story-category"]`

we can select

tag by `('div[class="medium-widget success-story-category"] p')`

we can also find with :

`find_h=browser.find_by_css('div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(2)')`

or

when html is

```
`<div class="row">

                    <div class="medium-widget success-story-category">
                        <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-get-started"></span>Getting Started</h2>
<p>Python can be easy to pick up whether you're a first time programmer or you're experienced with other languages. The following pages are a useful first step to get on your way writing programs with Python!</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers">Beginner's Guide, Programmers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers">Beginner's Guide, Non-Programmers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download">Beginner's Guide, Download &amp; Installation</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Examples">Code sample and snippets for Beginners</a></li>
</ul>

                    </div>

                    <div class="medium-widget success-story-category last">
                        <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-success-stories"></span>Friendly &amp; Easy to Learn</h2>
<p>The community hosts conferences and meetups, collaborates on code, and much more. Python's documentation will help you along the way, and the mailing lists will keep you in touch.</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/community/workshops/">Conferences and Workshops</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://docs.python.org">Python Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="/community/lists">Mailing Lists</a> and <a href="/community/irc/">IRC channels</a></li>
</ul>

                    </div>

                </div>`
```

by using :

```
`find_h=browser.find_by_css('div[class="row"]:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > p')
for i in find_h:
    print(i.text)`
```

we can capture image which is in a class by

`('div[class="image_class_name"] img')` and then `result["href" or "src"]`

example :

[image]

suppose i have to select that image then i can get it by this code :

```
find_h=browser.find_by_css('h1[class="site-headline"] img')
for i in find_h:
    print(i["src"])
```

Next question is how to select

tag : we can select

tag usng nth-child(n) :

So if i have this html code :

```
<div class="medium-widget success-story-category last">
                        <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-success-stories"></span>Friendly &amp; Easy to Learn</h2>
<p>The community hosts conferences and meetups, collaborates on code, and much more. Python's documentation will help you along the way, and the mailing lists will keep you in touch.</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/community/workshops/">Conferences and Workshops</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://docs.python.org">Python Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="/community/lists">Mailing Lists</a> and <a href="/community/irc/">IRC channels</a></li>
</ul>
                    </div>



<div class="medium-widget success-story-category last">
                        <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-success-stories"></span>Friendly &amp; Easy to Learn</h2>
<p>The community hosts conferences and meetups, collaborates on code, and much more. Python's documentation will help you along the way, and the mailing lists will keep you in touch.</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/community/workshops/">Conferences and Workshops</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://docs.python.org">Python Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="/community/lists">Mailing Lists</a> and <a href="/community/irc/">IRC channels</a></li>
</ul>
                    </div>
```

Then we can select href link of any

by using

```
div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a
```

Please remember nth-child(2) in `div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(1)`  doesn't select second nested div of this class instead nth-child(2) select second `medium-widget success-story-category last` class (as you can see there are two classes with same name `medium-widget success-story-category last`) .

Last answer of last question :

if there is `<class_name id="something">` :

then select like

```
class_name[id="something"]
```