# can we change the css , html values using splinter , beautiful soup or selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, beautifulsoup, splinter

can i change the value of any html , css thing using
   splinter or selenium like we can do with inspect element  :

```
  `<form action="/action_page.php"
oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
  0
  <input type="range" id="a" name="a" value="50">
  100 +
  <input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="50">
  =
  <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>`
```

can i select       `<input type="range" id="a" name="a" value="50">`
 and can change the value="30" by using splinter or selenium ?

Like if this is html code :

```
<div class="medium-widget success-story-category">
                        <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-get-started"></span>Getting Started</h2>
<p>Python can be easy to pick up whether you're a first time programmer or you're experienced with other languages. The following pages are a useful first step to get on your way writing programs with Python!</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers">Beginner's Guide, Programmers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers">Beginner's Guide, Non-Programmers</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download">Beginner's Guide, Download &amp; Installation</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Examples">Code sample and snippets for Beginners</a></li>
</ul>

                    </div>
```

- can i change `<p>` tag to `<h1>` ?
- can we add something to existing tag like `<p>` tag to

  to `<p style="color:red;">` ?

I tried to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911980/selenium-with-python-how-to-modify-an-element-css-style) question but have not found the solution.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium (with python) how to modify an element css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911980/selenium-with-python-how-to-modify-an-element-css-style)

Comment: @JeffC please remove duplicate tag , i asked using splinter . and second thing , that question doesn't have good anwers , even questioner have not accepted any answer .

Comment: You asked about Splinter or Selenium... it's stated in your question. The concept is the same in pretty much all languages anyway. You have to use javascript to do what you are asking and it involves using your bindings' version of execute script once you know the JS needed. Just because an answer hasn't been selected doesn't mean the answers aren't good. The core concepts are there if you take the time to study them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with those tools. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Show the example with sub questions which i ask there .