# Python Splinter Star Ratings

Tags: python-3.x, splinter

Given the star ratings under the "Recent Comments" section [here](https://www.greatschools.org/texas/harker-heights/3978-Harker-Heights-Elementary-School/),

I am trying to build a list of the star rating per comment shown on the page.
The trouble is that each star rating objects does not have a value.
For example, I can get an individual star object via xpath like this:

```
from splinter import Browser

url = 'https://www.greatschools.org/texas/harker-heights/3978-Harker-Heights-Elementary-School/'
browser.visit(url)

astar=browser.find_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[2]/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span[1]')
```

The rub is that I cannot seem to access the value (filled in or not) for the object astar.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="answer">
 <span class="five-stars">
  <span class="icon-star filled-star"></span>
  <span class="icon-star filled-star"></span>
  <span class="icon-star filled-star"></span>
  <span class="icon-star filled-star"></span>
  <span class="icon-star filled-star"></span>
 </span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
Some comments do not have star ratings at all, so I need to be able to determine if a particular comment has a star rating and, if so, what the rating is.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468030/how-select-class-div-tag-in-splinter) seems helpful for at least getting a list of all stars. I used it to do this:

```
stars = browser.find_by_css('span[class="icon-star filled-star"]')
```

So if I can get a list showing the sequence of if a comment has a star rating (something like ratings = [1,0,1,1...]) and the sequence of all stars (i.e. ['Filled', 'Filled', 'Empty'...]), I think I can piece together the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:
access the html attribute of each object like this:

```
#Get total number of comments
allcoms = len(browser.find_by_text('Overall experience'))

#Loop through all comments and gather into list
comments = []
#If pop-up box occurs, use div[4] instead of second div[5]
if browser.is_element_present_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[2]/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]'):
    use='4'
else:
    use='5'

for n in range(allcoms): #sometimes the second div[5] was div[4]
    comments.append(browser.find_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div['+use+']/div[2]/div[11]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div['+str(n+1)+']/div/div[2]').value)

#Get all corresponding star ratings
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468030/how-select-class-div-tag-in-splinter
ratingcode = []
ratings = browser.find_by_css('span[class="five-stars"]')
for a in range(len(comments)+2): #Add 2 to skip over first 2 ratings
    if a<2: #skip first 2 and last 3 because these are other ratings - by just using range(len(comments)) above to get correct # before stopping
        pass
    else:
        ratingcode.append(ratings[a].html)
```